# add a new choice to django choice fields

Tags: django

I'm working with Django and trying to create a dynamic choice fields, I've read a lot of posts but couldn't find a solution for my situation. I need to have one choice for "Add new element", so if the user can't find his choice, he will be able to add a new one.

The problem is how can I add then that option to the choices tuple. 
For example I have this:

```
YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = (

    ('OPTION1', 'OPTION1'),
    ('OPTION2', 'OPTION2'),
    ('Other', 'Other')
)
```

If the user selects 'Other', a new input element will appear, and when the user submits the new option I should have:

```
YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = (

    ('OPTION1', 'OPTION1'),
    ('OPTION2', 'OPTION2'),
    **('OptionAdded', 'OptionAdded'),**
    ('Other', 'Other')
)
```

Is there a way to do this?
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a pattern for "dynamic choices": it is called foreign keys.

Don't try and implement this by hacking the choices tuple. If you want your model to have a set of dynamic options, you should make a ForeignKey pointing at a separate model that records those choices.

Comment: good answer! I was trying so hardly to hack the choices tuple that didn't think in creating a Choices model. thanks!